# Prisma2: How to solve n +1 Problem with Paljs

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, prisma2

thx for any help.

Im using at the frontend the apollo-client and at the backend [graphql-nexus](https://nexusjs.org/docs/),prisma2 and graphql-yoga server.

I want to solve the n + 1 problem with @paljs/plugins.

At the frontend I have a query posts like:

```
query posts{
    posts {
        id
        favoritedBy(where: { id: { equals: $currentUserId } }) {
            id
        }
        author {
            id
            avatar {
                id
            }
        }
        link {
            id
        }
        games {
            id
        }
        tags {
            id
        }
        likes(where: { user: { id: { equals: $currentUserId } } }) {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

Posts resolver:

```
import { PrismaSelect } from '@paljs/plugins'
export const posts = queryField('posts', {
  type: 'Post',
  list: true,
  args: {
    ...
  },
  resolve: async (_parent, args, { prisma, request }, info) => {
    const select = new PrismaSelect(info).value
    let opArgs: FindManyPostArgs = {
      take: 10,
      orderBy: {
        [args.orderBy]: 'desc',
      },
      ...select
    }

    const post = await prisma.post.findMany(opArgs)
    
    //The result I want to return with the "sub-models" like likes, author tags...
    console.log(JSON.stringify(post, undefined, 2))

    return post
  },
})
```

I logging the queries

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query'],
})
```

My Problem: With PrismaSelect, I have 5 queries more than without and If I check the request-time at the frontend I need 300-400ms longer with PrismaSelect. So what I'm doing wrong?
I saw in the [@paljs/plugins](https://paljs.com/plugins/select#value) doc the select in the context. Maybe that is my mistake. How can I use the select in the context?

Here ist my Context:

```
import { PrismaClient, PrismaClientOptions } from '@prisma/client'
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-yoga'
import { PrismaDelete, onDeleteArgs } from '@paljs/plugins'

class Prisma extends PrismaClient {
  constructor(options?: PrismaClientOptions) {
    super(options)
  }

  async onDelete(args: onDeleteArgs) {
    const prismaDelete = new PrismaDelete(this)
    await prismaDelete.onDelete(args)
  }
}

export const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query'],
})
export const pubsub = new PubSub()

export interface Context {
  prisma: PrismaClient
  request: any
  pubsub: PubSub
}

export function createContext(request: any): Context {
  return { prisma, request, pubsub }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that to use my `PrismaSelect` plugin you need to remove the `nexus-prisma-plugin` package and use my Pal.js CLI to create your CRUD and ObjectType for nexus and using `@paljs/nexus` plugin to add in `mackSchema` function

```js
import { makeSchema } from '@nexus/schema';
import * as types from './graphql';
import { paljs } from '@paljs/nexus'; // import our plugin

export const schema = makeSchema({
  types,
  plugins: [paljs()],// here our plugin don't use nexus-prisma-plugin
  outputs: {
    schema: __dirname + '/generated/schema.graphql',
    typegen: __dirname + '/generated/nexus.ts',
  },
  typegenAutoConfig: {
    sources: [
      {
        source: require.resolve('./context'),
        alias: 'Context',
      },
    ],
    contextType: 'Context.Context',
  },
});
```

Now add this type to your `Context`

```js
export interface Context {
  prisma: PrismaClient
  request: any
  pubsub: PubSub
  select: any // here our select type
}
export function createContext(request: any): Context {
// our paljs plugin will add select object before resolver
  return { prisma, request, pubsub, select: {} }
}
```

after you add our plugin your query will log like this

```js
extendType({
  type: 'Query',
  definition(t) {
    t.field('findOneUser', {
      type: 'User',
      nullable: true,
      args: {
        where: arg({
          type: 'UserWhereUniqueInput',
          nullable: false,
        }),
      },
      resolve(_, { where }, { prisma, select }) {
// our plugin add select object into context for you
        return prisma.user.findOne({
          where,
          ...select,
        });
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Can you please try to use my `pal c` command to start an example from my list and try your schema and make tests with it

Answer (score 0):

It is working, thx Ahmed your plugin is AWESOME!!!!!

I changed my Post-Object from

```
const Post = objectType({
  name: 'Post',
  definition(t) {
    t.model.id()
    t.model.authorId()
    t.model.tags()
    t.model.games()
    t.model.link()
    t.model.report()
    t.model.notifications()
    t.model.author()
    t.model.favoritedBy({
      filtering: {
        id: true,
      },
    })
    t.model.likes({
      filtering: {
        user: true,
      },
    })
  }
})
```

to

```
const Post = objectType({
  name: 'Post',
  definition(t) {
    t.string('id')
    t.field('tags', {
      nullable: false,
      list: [true],
      type: 'Tag',
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['tags']
      },
    })
    t.field('games', {
      list: [true],
      type: 'Game',
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['games']
      },
    })
    t.field('link', {
      type: 'Link',
      nullable: true,
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['link']
      },
    })
    t.field('notifications', {
      list: [true],
      type: 'Notification',
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['notifications']
      },
    })
    t.field('author', {
      nullable: false,
      type: 'User',
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['author']
      },
    })
    t.field('favoritedBy', {
      nullable: false,
      list: [true],
      type: 'User',
      args: {
        where: 'UserWhereInput',
      },
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['favoritedBy']
      },
    })
    t.field('likes', {
      list: [true],
      type: 'Like',
      args: {
        where: 'LikeWhereInput',
      },
      resolve(parent: any) {
        return parent['likes']
      },
    })
  },
})
```

And I also used the nexus-prisma-plugin and paljs-plugin at the same time

Comment: But can I know where are you using `nexus-prisma-plugin`? and don't convert the types by your self you can use my `@paljs/cli` `pal g` command to auto-generate all types

Comment: I used the nexus-prisma-plugin. Now I'm using paljs. The pal g command is awesome. Makes it very easy and productive. Thx again.  My answer to my post was without the @paljs/cli. But now I'm using the @paljs/cli with the generate command.

Comment: I am pleased to help you